# Can't type in console IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When I try to run using `Run`, I can't write anything. All that works is <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> (maybe some more shortcuts work). It's obviously not about the code, because everything works correctly through the terminal window.

I tried to rebuild the project, I tried invalidate caches.

[image]

Comment: did it work before? If so, have you installed or updated any plugin since? Trial and error disabling those..

Comment: everything worked, I didn't install any plugins, but I tried to disable the existing plugins

Comment: Please restore all the plugins, or maybe try this menu to see if it helps: File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...